# Dist/Sort key for Redshift time series database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am involved in a time series telemetry project, where we store data into Amazon Redshift. We have a `timestamp` column for collection time. And `ClientID`, `IOt-ID` indicating a unique IOT device within a client.

All our queries are time bound in the sense we query for a particular day/week/month. Would the following be a good dist/sort key ?

- Distribution key - (Clientid, IOT-ID)
- Sort key - timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule for Amazon Redshift is:

- Set the **Distribution Key** to the field normally used to `JOIN` with other tables. This will put all data for a given value of that column on the same slice, making it easier to `JOIN` with other tables that have the same DISTKEY.
- Set the **Sort Key** to the field that is most commonly used in a `WHERE` statement. Rows will be stored in order of this field, making it easier to "skip over" disk blocks that do *not* contain the desired data. (This is *very* powerful.)

So, it sounds like your `timestamp` field is ideal as the `SORTKEY`.

The choice of `DISTKEY` depends on how you JOIN, but can also help `GROUP BY` since the relevant data is co-located.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will be using the timestamp field as Sort key and they will be going in to my queries in the where clause to retrieve time bound data.  With that said, I am also looking to do a "Order by" clause with a different field in the same table. And I believe an order by clause on a field which is not part of sort key will be slow.  How can i make order by clause on an non sort key faster? worst case I will be doing a sort in code after bringing the records into memory of the application.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` only operates on the result set, so it probably won't be improved by a `SORT KEY`. You could do an experiment to compare the query time with/without the `ORDER BY` to see whether it has much of an impact. (Be sure to turn off [Result Caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_challenges_achieving_high_performance_queries.html#result-caching) when performing such tests.)